# How to update a RecyclerView with asynchrony function

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update my recycler view each time the user launch the activity. all the data is saved in SQLite.

The easy way I'm doing is to clear the list attached to the adapter and add a new one like this.

```
 public void set(List<contacts> list) {
        final sql s = sql.getInstance(getContext());


       if (ContactsList != null) {
           ContactsList.clear();
           ContactsList.addAll(list);
           cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }

    }
```

This function is working fine, but it consumes a lot of memory

```
Skipped xx frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Can I do that in background using handler ??

Is there any way to update the recycler view with another list async

Answer (score 1):

you need to see what is taking the time off the main thread (probably the SQL query) and move it off the UI.

I would strongly suggest 2 things:

1. running [traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)
2. using [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) for your SQL connection

Answer (score -1):

I hope that you have a list of elements in your adapter ,and addAll is just adding to your list.

So what you can do is to create new Thread (AsyncTask if you like) and run notifyDataSetChange on Ui Thread. Something like

```
    public void set(List<contacts> list) {
            final sql s = sql.getInstance(getContext());


           if (ContactsList != null) {
               new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                        ContactsList.clear();
                        ContactsList.addAll(list);
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(
                           new  Runnable() {Handler(Looper.myLopper()) 
                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {                                                       
                                  ContactsList.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                  }
                              }); 
                            }
                        }.start
           }

        }
```

Comment: creating a new thread (instead of using a thread pool), every time you update the list is not only a terrible idea but you're also doing it to what's probably the fast part of this method

Comment: I didnt focus on what is taking a lot of time on his code, i just gave him a solution how to move it out of main thread. From his post there is no possibility to find out what hard-use memory. But maybe you know what is sql class. And you assume that there is some query. Where?